# how to show json (array)response in html page using javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have some json response which contains data in array format.i have to display that data one by one in html page.in my html page i added some div element for merchantname,productname and remove button.and json data contanins array of same product name,merchant name,remove button for specific merchant.now when i am displaying data in page its showing me all the name of merchant after that list of product.means it is like
merchant name:abc
merchantname:xyz

productname:a1
productname:a2
remove button for merchant1
remove button for merchant2
but i want to display this data like
merchantname:abc
productname:a1
remove button for merchnant1
merchantname:xyz
productname:a2
remove button for merchnant2
 this is the code

```
$("#merchantname").append("<font color='green'>"+(responseObj.merchants.merchantname[i])+"</font>"+"\n");
    $("#productname").append(responseObj.merchants.productname[i]+"\n");

    $("#remove").append("<input type='button' value='remove' onClick='remove(needID)'>"+"</input>"+"\n");
```

Comment: Use `jsrender` or simply iterate the json array to append in your page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem I have written a small piece of code which may help answer the question.

I'll try to answer any question of yours.

```
//Create the dom from the json response
$.each(responseObj.merchants,function(index){
    record=$('<div/>',{'class':'record'});
    merchantname=$('<span/>',{'class':'merchant'});
    merchantname.text(responseObj.merchants[index].merchantname);

    productname=$('<span/>',{'class':'product'});
    productname.text(responseObj.merchants[index].productname);

    remove=$('<input/>',{'class':'remove','val':'Remove','type':'button'});

    record.append(merchantname).append(productname).append(remove);

    $('#view').append(record);
});

// Handler for the remove button
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
// Statement to remove record
    $(this).closest('.record').remove();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uFK7f/)

Comment: see this is json "needs":{"customerNeeds":[{"needTitle":"Need a Mobile","needDescription":"Android","fromCustomer":"xyz ","needDate":"2013-12-20T07:39:39Z","needID":4,"needStatus":"pending"} ]} now i want to print needtitle ,i wrote like $.each(response.needs, function (i, needs) {
     alert(needs.customerNeeds.needTitle);
    });but its not showing anything.correct me what i m doing wrong here.

Comment: thanks for this .but pls see this i tried but i want one by one data means need a bike ,after that its need id...not all need after all need id..http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/9c2Tn/

Comment: @user3415421 Can you please be a bit more clear on your last comment? I'm afraid to say I'm not able to understand.

Comment: yes sure..from ur link i tried ,i m getting right data but for designing purpose i want data should be displayed like all the info of first need then all the info of second need one by one..means suppose i m havving needtitle and need date.then i want data should be displayed like first needid,its need date then second need title ,second need date,but what i m getting is first needtitle,second needtitle,first need id,second need id  which i dont want.i know the error also as i m appending it to div thats why its showing like this.but if u have any other idea.then pls tell me.

Comment: Can you share with me the code that you are trying in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/9c2Tn/2/ see this link.here all need title are displayed after that all need descriptions are displayed but what i want is need,its description means output like need a mobile android,need a car mercedez, need a bike bajaj hope u understand.

Comment: Please update the fiddle and then share. You have to click on the Update button next to the Run button to update. Also when you update the link changes. You are sharing the same link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9c2Tn/3/ see..now tell me...here i m getting need a mobile need a car need a bike and then all description kike android mercedez.but what i want is need a mobile android,need a bike bajaj.like this ..now got it..?

Comment: Oh I understand now. I have re-written the code for you. Actually, all the record divs should be appended to the same div with id view. Since you were appending to two different divs, it was not coming as you wanted. Please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/9c2Tn/4/.

Comment: can i write this ("<h3>"+responseObj.merchants[index].merchantname+"</h3>");means i want that text to be displayed in some format.i tried this but its not working.

Comment: @user3415421 If you are satisfied with the answer please accept it.

Comment: There should be a tick/checkmark near the top left corner of my answer. It should be below the down arrow (which is use to downvote).